# What do you call a situation where the pooled database connection is not used immediately?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

While running through a piece of code for performance tuning, i noticed that the pooled database connection is not used immediately, it follows some pre-processing before the connection used to delegate a SQL update call.

I fixed the codes by delaying the retrieval of the pooled database connection until before the codes is ready to call on the insert method.

As i am trying to update the documentation that this optimization is done, how should i work it in a sentence or title?

Old Codes:

```
... 

connection = ConnectionFactory.getPooledConnection(); // get pooled connection

String message = StringUtils.replace(log, "a", "b");

// many other processing

connection.update(message);

connection.release();
...
```

New Codes:

```
... 


String message = StringUtils.replace(log, "a", "b");

// many other processing

connection = ConnectionFactory.getPooledConnection(); // get pooled connection

connection.update(message);

connection.release();
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this case actually warrants it - because you've made the code behave more like it "should". But generally, such deferral of work until the moment it is needed is referred to as "lazy initialization".